# How fix the device icon in macOS Finder's Network location?

Tags: samba, finder, raspbian, macos-catalina

This is probably not a macOS (Catalina) problem, but rather a Raspberry Pi-problem. All I did was install the latest Raspbian buster on a Pi 4. (I also installed samba).

Is something perhaps wrongly configured?

How does macOS decide which icon to use for network devices?

[image: strange icon for network device]

Answer (score 4):

Apparently what I needed to add to the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file was

```
[global]
    min protocol = SMB2
    vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
    fruit:metadata = stream
    fruit:model = RackMac
    fruit:posix_rename = yes
    fruit:veto_appledouble = no
    fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
    fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
```